# Python: variable in nested if else won't run

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

The variable C won't run in the following code:

```
A = raw_input("How are you today")
if A == "Good" or "Fine" or "good" or "fine" or "great" or "Great" or "Wonderful" or "wonderful":
  print("I am glad you are having a good day")
    B = raw_input("What made your day good")
    if B == "everything" or "Everthing":
        print("Everything! You must be having a very good day")
    else:
        print("It sounds like you had a very intersting day")

        C = raw_input("Do you want to hear about my day? [y/n]")
        if C == "y" or "Y":
            print("I sat around as an unused computer!")
        else:
            print("I guess I am just an annoying computer")
else:
    print("I am sorry you are having a bad day")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Please format your code properly for your next StackOverflow question. It's impossible to debug Python with improper indentation. In this case it's easy to see what's happened because you've made a very common mistake. Please see the linked question for your answer.

Comment: The last `else` statement has no corresponding `if`.

Answer (score 0):

you are making the compare as you say it while it should be always A == X or A== Y and so on

another way to make you type less is to use in operator in list.

like this

```
A = "Wonderful"
if A in ["Good","Fine","good","fine","great","Great","Wonderful","wonderful"]:
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

that will make you type less and have the same results instead of repeating A==X for every case

you have to do that for all variables A,B and C

Answer (score -1):

You have to compare every time in the if statement.
 Suppose you are trying to do this:

```
>>> b = "bhansa"
>>> if b== "A" or "B":
    print "yes"


yes
```

Which is not true.

```
A = raw_input("How are you today")
if A == "Good" or A=="Fine" or A=="good" or A=="fine" or A=="great" or A=="Great" or A=="Wonderful" or A=="wonderful":
  print("I am glad you are having a good day")
  B = raw_input("What made your day good")
  if B == "everything" or B=="Everthing":
    print("Everything! You must be having a very good day")
  else:
    print("It sounds like you had a very intersting day")
    C = raw_input("Do you want to hear about my day? [y/n]")
    if C == "y" or C=="Y":
      print("I sat around as an unused computer!")
    else:
      print("I guess I am just an annoying computer")
else:
  print("I am sorry you are having a bad day")
```